# Check stream being successfully streamed when using within an <iframe> tag

Tags: javascript, html

My stream sometimes can play and sometimes it doesn't. I want to check when the stream can be played and when it can not. Below is when the stream can play.

```
<html>
  <header></header>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://iframe.cloudflarestream.com/eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE2MWJhNGZiMmM1NWUxMzIxNjA3M2Y1MmRkM2ZjZTA4In0.eyJzdWIiOiIyMGE5ZDVhY2M0YmQ4MmE1Nzk0MGVkOTNkOWVhZWFkZSIsImtpZCI6IjE2MWJhNGZiMmM1NWUxMzIxNjA3M2Y1MmRkM2ZjZTA4IiwiZXhwIjoxNzI3NTA0MTY1fQ.Be8Kti5lX2RnVLHoufmBL7O9jAzuUjysc-ACRiun24Qt4z8lRvaAhORCW0DLXuRWZKr2MyAx660b-aQ7n0MZOyZgIYYEOf0H6qNCeahNenuD7Mg_MgJvrHgBtRnV7UbHbFfvAyZSluiIbjnFC-3ngnfVVOrZtwoXwl9pwRVYBi-5YaXXzsw_dLADw07bYwNer55rjk5IGw_QTvC0BoZvGFeAZ1rsd6Kv2m3bqGShvzYjHgOc97kK1Ly4-rKsc_p6jvmJyKFJDdsGobKVhCU5inmi6ys7NSDh7YqCiDCUVTzdsb766B95EZ-2SK-DqMMFCs3Fn_vQPRJdDfhd7zvucQ?preload=metadata"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

And when the stream can't play:

```
<html>
  <header></header>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://iframe.cloudflarestream.com/eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE2MWJhNGZiMmM1NWUxMzIxNjA3M2Y1MmRkM2ZjZTA4In0.eyJzdWIiOiIyMGE5ZDVhY2M0YmQ4MmE1Nzk0MGVkOTNkOWVhZWFkZSIsImtpZCI6IjE2MWJhNGZiMmM1NWUxMzIxNjA3M2Y1MmRkM2ZjZTA4IiwiZXhwIjoxNzI3NTA0MTY1fQ.Be8Kti5lX2RnVLHoufmBL7O9jAzuUjysc-ACRiun24Qt4z8lRvaAhORCW0DLXuRWZKr2MyAx660b-aQ7n0MZOyZgIYYEOf0H6qNCeahNenuD7Mg_MgJvrHgBtRnV7UbHbFfvAyZSluiIbjnFC-3ngnfVVOrZtwoXwl9pwRVYBi-5YaXXzsw_dLADw07bYwNr55rjk5IGw_QTvC0BoZvGFeAZ1rsd6Kv2m3bqGShvzYjHgOc97kK1Ly4-rKsc_p6jvmJyKFJDdsGobKVhCU5inmi6ys7NSDh7YqCiDCUVTzdsb766B95EZ-2SK-DqMMFCs3Fn_vQPRJdDfhd7zvucQ?preload=metadata"/>
  </body>
</html>
```